# Why am I being asked to purchase $502/$25 Google Play gift cards by customer support to unlock my account?

Tags: facebook, privacy

Spoke with customer support yesterday, they told me in order to verifying was the actual owner of my Facebook account I would have to purchase 2 $25 google play gift cards to verify my location because my account was hacked your someone in Nigeria, changed email, phone and password so I cannot access my account or request codes to reset password.  After I gave him the google numbers he said the session was timed out so I need to buy additional gift cards because I cannot open a new case with the numbers from the cards I had already given. If there was not a language barrier it would have been a lot easier to communicate. Now I am out $50 and I am still not able to access my account. I am very disappointed with the fact that Facebook has you purchase $50 worth of google play gift cards for no reason whatsoever, once the access codes are given there is no way for me to use the $25 gift cards. Especially because I was hacked in the first place. Ask me any of my personal information or previous posts and I can give you that info. Don’t make me feel more insecure about the person in Nigeria having all of my info, places I’ve checked in, pictures of my kids and other personal info about me.

Comment: That wasn't proper facebook customer support. Basically the hacker is holding your account to ransom, and the ransom would seem to be multiple Google Play gift cards. I'm sorry to tell you that you've been scammed by the sounds of it.

Comment: I suspect you fell for a scam

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer because you are getting scammed. They wanted $25 of android credit and then wanted to try again. Assuming that "google numbers" means the number hidden under the scratch-off foil.

Start distrusting. Do not trust your smartphone, computer, anyone **you** did not contact directly and most of all **do not trust the internet**. It is basically the 21st century wild-west. This is not really the place but you need to get it together fast.

Using a third-party (as in not owned by you or used in the same property as you) computer ask google for facebooks contact details and tell them what has happened. The reason for not using your computer is that if your computer or smartphone is directly compromised (hacked) then it is trivial to make it look like you are visiting the genuine fb site or even google but with say contact numbers changed to ones they control.

If you reuse passwords then you need to secure your digital banking / financial services ASAP by getting in contact with them and that goes for email accounts too as if your password is re-used and compromised then they can simply perform password resets for any web accounts linked to that email.

> Ask me any of my personal information or previous posts and I can give you that info.

From a security point of view, applicable to all web users, this statement is terrifying. Distrust, distrust, distrust.